# running a script in the background with php

Tags: php, shell

i have a php function that dispatches a certain post to all the users concerned about that post. 
since sometimes there might be up to 100 000 users concerned about that post. it means that this function needs to be repeated 100 000 times thus it will take forever.
i wanna know if there is a way to run the iterations in the background but at the same time, the user who posted the answer doesnt have to wait all that time. 
i'm thinking about just telling the user that the email was sent to all the users and instead of waiting till all the posts were sent just run another script in shell in  the background from php.

do you guys think it's the best solution. and if not, whats the best way to do all the processing in the background ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your background task into [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

It could be something like this:

- You have a list of user to be notified in table
- create a script that will do:

  - at every script run, it will fetch several rows for processing
  - once row is processed, update it as finished
- set this script to run at xxx minutes.

**UPDATE**

Actually, there is another trick:

1. you have list of user to be notified in `users_tobenotified` table.
2. you have PHP script as cron that will read on that table and generate text files in some directory called `/data/cron/tobenotified`. This file contain something like this:

   ```
   [date]\t[time]\t[post-entry]\t[user-tobenotified]\t[someotherinfo]
   ```
3. have another PHP script as cron that will loop through `/data/cron/tobenotified` and read each files and then process it.
4. test ... test ... test ...
5. profit!

Comment: sorry but can you give me more details ?

Comment: take a look [here](http://service.futurequest.net/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=30)

Comment: thank you very much. however can i make it run from php whenever i want ?

Comment: yup, sure you can. The script is basically, just like you run it on browser. It just, processing limited amount or rows on every run.

Answer (score 1):

Adding asynchronous activities like this to a PHP script is not simple, but can add a huge performance gain, like you are looking for.

### Approach One

Store the to-be-done emails, or some metadata about them in a database, and mark them as processed:false.  Then, a cron job, or some other daemon/process running on the server periodically checks that database table for emails to be sent, or whatever it is you are offloading.  This is probably the safest, as you have a record of when things were requested, and then actually sent.

### Approach Two

For a particularly tricky job I had to accomplish, I actually fired off a bash command which ran in the background:

```
$job = "/bin/myscript $param1 $param2";             
$job = "$job > /dev/null 2> /dev/null";
$cmd = "bash -c \"$job &\"";
exec($cmd)
```

Note that in this case, you really have no control over things after exec() is called.

**Others**

Here is an example similar to my approach #2:
http://robert.accettura.com/blog/2006/09/14/asynchronous-processing-with-php/

Gearman is another tool for approaching asynchronous PHP tasks. They even mention that "Zend Framework is now using it for executing post-commit hooks without having the committer experience delays"
http://css.dzone.com/articles/asynchronous-processing-php

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to notify each user individually via email?

Why don't just send 1 email with all your users email addresses on the BCC field?